# How do I split a dataframe column and move the front part of the column name into its own column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I've a dataframe in this structure:

| Date | user_count_target | user_count_actual | user_count_forecast | sales_target | sales_actual | sales_forecast |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 123 | 113 | 103 | 83 | 12 | 13 |
| 2022-02-01 | 110 | 100 | 105 | 90 | 75 | 100 |

I'd like to split it on the column name, but move the front part of the column name (which corresponds to the metric name) into a separate column of its own. The front part (i.e. the metric name) can be of any length, but the last part will always be either "target", "actual" or "forecast".

I eventually want it in this structure:

| Date | metric | target | actual | forecast |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | user_count | 123 | 113 | 103 |
| 2022-01-01 | sales | 83 | 12 | 13 |
| 2022-02-01 | user_count | 110 | 100 | 105 |
| 2022-02-01 | sales | 90 | 75 | 100 |

Would appreciate any R solution that you can offer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This approach with `dplyr` and `tidyr` could work

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyr)

df <- tibble(
  Date = c('2022-01-01', '2022-02-01'),
  user_target = c(123,110),
  user_actual = c(113,100),
  user_forecast = c(103,105),
  sales_target = c(83,90),
  sales_actual = c(12,75),
  sales_forecast = c(13,100)
)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Date,
               names_to = c('metric', 'values'),
               values_to = 'value',
               names_sep = '_') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = values,
              values_from = value)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   Date       metric target actual forecast
#>   <chr>      <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 2022-01-01 user      123    113      103
#> 2 2022-01-01 sales      83     12       13
#> 3 2022-02-01 user      110    100      105
#> 4 2022-02-01 sales      90     75      100
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! But what if the metric contains an "_" like user_count?